# Disabling jQuery click function at certain window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, click

I'm designing a responsive website and am using media queries to handle the responsiveness. However along with the CSS I want to disable certain jQuery click functions at a certain window width.

Right now I can do this successfully on page load but I want to also be able to do it assuming the user resized the window.

**(paragraph 3)** So for example if the user starts off with a really big window on his/her computer and he/she resizes it to be a very small window he/she should not be able to activate the click functions anymore. Conversely if a user starts off with a very small window on his/her computer and resizes it to be very big he/she should be able to activate the click functions.

I have tried multiple solutions but none seem to work.

Basically I want to make some clickable objects not clickable anymore or at least have them click and do nothing at a certain window width.

**Simply checking at page load and no other time makes it so that what should happen in paragraph 3 doesn't happen.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('#portclick').click(function(){
      $('#pagecont').slideToggle(500);
      $('#icons').slideToggle(500);
})}})

$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('#name').click(function(){
      $('#projects').slideToggle(500);
})}})
```

I tried remove the id attribute that I'm using to call the function on at certain window widths and readd them at the width but this doesn't seem to work either. Removing the id doesn't seem to disable to click function at all.

And my most recent solution which comes the closest is just to bind the click function to window resize. So far this works but it is extremely buggy so when you get to a width where the click function works and you try clicking it will do the toggle function about 100 times before it stops. But it does sustain the condition described in paragraph 3.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('#portclick').click(function(){
      $('#pagecont').slideToggle(500);
      $('#icons').slideToggle(500);
  })}
  else return})

$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('#name').click(function(){
      $('#projects').slideToggle(500);
  })}
  else return})
```

Does anybody have an idea for a working solution that would work flawlessly like css media queries do? I don't think this is that complicated of a problem to work around so I'm hoping for some good answers! Thank you guys so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Several problems here. First, `resize` fires almost constantly while the window is moving, so don't actually trigger anything on that. Second, you should only bind your event handlers once (or if you must bind more than once, make sure you clear out the old ones.) You can simplify thusly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isLargeWindow;
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        isLargeWindow = $(this).width() > 992;
    });

    $('#whatever').on('click', function(e) {
        if (isLargeWindow)
            // do large window stuff
        else
            // do small window stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My simplest way of doing that is not using the `resize` event at all just attach 
the click event and add an early return term if the window size doesn't suite your needs.

Example code:

```
$('#portclick').click(function(){
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    /* You can add an height value too */ 
    winHeight = $(window).height();
    if ( winWidth < 992 ) return;
    /* Youe Code Executes */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `if` statement to be called after the resize has happened then do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sLk5ro6c/1/

```
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    window.resizeEvt;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);
        window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function () {
            doneresizing();
        }, 250);
    });
});

function doneresizing() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
        alert('example');
    }
}
```

This way the code won't be called every time during the resizing of the window